# SQL query to select last non null node.attribute/field

Tags: sql

Let say my table looks like this

```
Point-ID | Pos-1 | Pos-2 | Pos-3 | Pos-4  
---------|-------|-------|-------|-------
P1       | a1    | a2    | Null  | NULL  
P2       | b1    | b2    | b3    | NULL   
P3       | c1    | c2    | c3    | c4    
P4       | d1    | Null  | Null  | Null  
P5       | e1    | e2    | e3    | e4
```

From the above I want to select the first Pos & the last null pos so that my resultant table looks like this

```
Point-ID | Start | End   
---------|-------|-------
P1       | a1    | a2    
P2       | b1    | b3    
P3       | c1    | c4    
P4       | d1    | d1
P5       | e1    | e4
```

**Any idea how to do it?** So far what I could think of is something like

```
Select 
    Point-ID,
    (CASE
        WHEN Pos-4 is not null then Pos-4
        WHEN Pos-3 is not null then Pos-3
        WHEN Pos-2 is not null then Pos-2
        WHEN Pos-1 is not null then Pos-1
        ELSE null
    END) as Start,
    (CASE
        WHEN Pos-4 is not null then Pos-4
        WHEN Pos-3 is not null then Pos-3
        WHEN Pos-2 is not null then Pos-2
        WHEN Pos-1 is not null then Pos-1
        ELSE null
    END) as End
FROM myTable
```

p.s I am going be using PROC SQL in SAS Base

Comment: other than swapping the order for the `start`, it looks like your select case statement will work, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with function [`COALESCE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002206368.htm):

```
SELECT Point-ID,
    COALESCE(Pos-1, Pos-2, Pos-3, Pos-4) as Start,
    COALESCE(Pos-4, Pos-3, Pos-2, Pos-1) as End
FROM myTable
```

`COALESCE` selects first non null value, so in case of start you make sure to pass columns from 1 to 4, and for end - in the opposite order.

Comment: Yes, both work.. thanks
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b482/6 & http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b482/5